# SpacePy: "ImportError: cannot import name irbempylib"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I downloaded spacepy via easy_install.exe in the command prompt and this code doesn't raise an error:

```
import spacepy.coordinates as coord
from spacepy.time import Ticktock
import numpy as np
def geotomag(alt,lat,lon):
    #call with altitude in kilometers and lat/lon in degrees 
    Re=6371.0 #mean Earth radius in kilometers
    #setup the geographic coordinate object with altitude in earth radii 
    cvals = coord.Coords([np.float((alt/Re+Re))/Re,np.float(lat),np.float(lon)], 'GEO', 'sph',['Re','deg','deg'])
    #set time epoch for coordinates:
    cvals.ticks=Ticktock(['2012-01-01T12:00:00'], 'ISO')
    #return the magnetic coords in the same units as the geographic:
    return cvals.convert('MAG','sph')
```

When I try to call the function, however, it gives me "ImportError: cannot import name irbempylib".

Irbempylib is supposed to be included in spacepy as evidenced by the help doc:

```
PACKAGE CONTENTS
    LANLstar
    coordinates
    data_assimilation
    datamodel
    empiricals
    irbempy (package)
    lib
    omni
    plot (package)
    poppy
    pybats (package)
    pycdf (package)
    radbelt
    rst
    seapy
    spacepy_EnKF
    time
    toolbox (package)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I also had had this problem. I think it is to do with the missing source files for irbempylib with a particuar version of SpacePy.

To fix this I deleted all references to SpacePy (files and folder(s)) from the "site-packages" folder of your Python installation. Then did a fresh install of SpacePy using Pip: `pip install spacepy`. This downloaded and installed SpacePy version 0.1.5.

Re-run your Python code and it should work (it did for me!)